# Solve for x: $y=9x-x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve $y=9x-x^3$ for x. I need the x= because I am doing the volume of a solid of revolution around the y-axis involving this formula. I know how to solve simpler problems but this one I don't know how to solve for x.

Comment: You don't need to solve this one for $x$ in order to do volume of revolution.

Comment: @jgon, Well I need to set up the integral to find the volume of the region bounded by $y=9x-x^3$ and the line $y=-7(x-4)-28$ in the first quadrant when it is revolved about the y-axis.

Comment: @Quantitative You can use the disk method, then the integration should be in terms of dx and the given functions

Comment: @CivilSigma isn't that the shell method in this case? Or am I forgetting my single variable calc again?

Comment: There **is** a formula for $x$ in terms of $y$, the [Cardano Formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) It is useless for your purposes. Use Cylindrical Shells for the volume calculation.

Comment: The curves intersect at $x=0$ and $x=4.$  The upper curve is $y=9x-x^3.$  Although disk method is possible,  the shell is the most natural in this case.   Recall the integral is $2\pi \int^b_a r h \ dx,$ where $r$ is the radius of the cylindrical shell ($r=x$ in your case) and $h$ is the height of the shell (So $h=(9x-x^3) - (-7(x-4)-28).$ )